# COMO MANIPULAR EL BOTON FISICO "BACK" _ En React, sobre dispositivo Android

Tags: android, reactjs, app

Estoy trabajando sobre una APP, la cual cuenta con los componentes 'App', donde se establecen los componentes definiéndolos como Stack.
También cuenta con un componente Home, y varios componentes mas que definen vistas para hacer distintas tareas.

La cuestión es la siguiente. Estoy un poco mareado de como debería implementar la funcionalidad cuando se presiona el botón físico ATRAS de un teléfono con ANDROID.

Entiendo que se aplica this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this); y en el componentWillMount agrego BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handler).

Pero la cuestiones son las siguiente:
-¿Lo mejor es armar un Custom Hook para reutilizarlo en cualquier componente?
-Si paso a de home a una vista, y luego a otra ¿debo tener una funcion independiente go back para regresar a la primera vista o hay otra forma de aplicarlo dentro de la funcion handleBackButtonClick ?
-Para salir de la aplicación estando sobre Home. Debería preguntar si me encuentro en home con navigate y si es asi salir de la aplicacion con BackHandler.exitApp()? y sino aplicar lo normal de handleBackButtonClick ?

En resumen...las 3 acciones se aplican sobre la misma función de handleBackButtonClick y a su vez handleBackButtonClick tendria que ser un hook si quiero aplicarlo en todas las vistas o debo separar en funciones distintas...para regresar a atras, para salir a home, y para salir de la aplicacion?

Comment: Por favor, delimita el planteamiento a un problema _específico_. Las preguntas muy amplias y/o basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Es necesaria la explicacion para que se entienda el problema. Saludos!

Comment: Y está perfecto, pero fijate que tenés múltiples preguntas en un enunciado. Además, preguntar por "lo mejor" deriva en que te respondan en base a opiniones. Leé [ask].

Comment: Asi es, en base a mi pregunta también planteo un problema, en el cual estoy necesitando claramente ayuda, por eso explico lo que esta al alcance de mi comprension, para que me saquen la duda si estoy errado o no en las ideas y en la idea general que planteo. Gracias por tu respuesta pero entiendo por consultas que vi en esta pagina satck overflow, que se pueden hacer este tipo de preguntas.

Vi ejemplos de implementar lo que planteo en una de las preguntas. Pero solo termina realizando una accion. Y no varias como explique.. por eso pregunto explicando el contexto.